# Actionscript 3 - load and library image on increment / counter

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a very simple flash movie.

- 24 png images in the Library
- The image properties are set to 'Export for Actionscript' and the class named 'image1', 'image2' etc
- Single frame in the timeline

I need to dynamically load 'image1' on the stage at the start of the movie. I have been able to do this using BitmapData ojects.

On clicking the image, I need to increment an internal image and replace the image on screen with image2.

When I try to pass the library class as a variable it throws an error.

Can anyone help me with an example?

Any questions, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading externally might be handy, but the library approach is doable.
You need to either use loaderInfo's applicationDomain's [getDefinition()](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition()) method, or
[flash.utils.getDefinitionByName();](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29)

application domain example:

```
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < imagesNum ; i++){
    var ImageClass:Class = this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition('YourLinkageID'+i) as Class;
    //I add 0,0 because since you have png, they will extend BitmapData which has width and height as compulsory 
    //constructor arguments. If the thing doesn't look right, use the actual dimensions instead of 0,0
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new ImageClass(0,0));
    //display it or do whatever
}
```

getDefinitionByName example:

```
import flash.utils.*;

for(var i:int = 0 ; i < imagesNum ; i++){
    var ImageClass:Class = getDefinitionByName('YourLinkageID'+i) as Class;
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new ImageClass(0,0));
    //display it or do whatever
}
```

HTH,
George

Answer (score 0):

You would be better creating a class and loading the images in using the Loader class. Is it imperitive you have the images in the library?