# dynamically adding children from library using array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i'm porting an old AS2 project to AS3, And have encounter a problem. I've tried a few different things but had no success.

in AS2 when dynamically attaching a MC from the library i would sometimes use an array. the array would hold linkage reference's,  like so;

```
var mc:String = state_ar[currentState];
this.container.attachMovie(mc,mc,this.getNextHighestDepth());
targetMC = this.container[mc];
```

How would i do this in AS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do that using [getDefinition()](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition%28%29) or [getDefinitionByName()](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29)

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101827/actionscript-3-load-and-library-image-on-increment-counter/2101951#2101951) for **code**, your situation sounds quite similar.

*Note:* The only difference is you might be using MovieClips, not images, so you won't need the 0,0 arguments in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking but I'll give it a shot.

```
//New array to store Movie Clips references    
var myArray:Array = new Array();
//Create a movie clip
var movieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
//Add it to the array for reference
myArray.push(movieClip);
//Put it on the stage
this.addChild(movieClip);
```

You can still use arrays to store references to an object and you can reference them directly.

---

In as3 the MovieClips in the library will have a class name, so if you have a MC in the library called MyMovie you would add it in as3 with:

```
var myMovie:MyMovie = new MyMovie();
addChild(myMovie);
```

Comment: sorry,
i didn't explain myself very well. the array was used to store (what were called in AS2) linkages.

for example;
i have 3 different movieClips in my library, each with there own different linkage id. 

i create an array; 
state_ar = ['link_1','link_2','link_3'];  

then reference an index from the array; 
var linkageID:String = state_ar[0], 

then attach the movie;
attachMovie(linkageID,linkageID, this.getNextHighestDepth()).

Comment: As3 is object oriented so you create and add movieclips by instancing them see my edited code. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your response TripWired, but the question refers to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Answer;

```
var mc:String = state_ar[currentState];
var classReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(mc) as Class;
var tempMC:Object = new classReference();
this.container.addChild(tempMC)
```

Thanks George